# failed to interpret date regular expression

Tags: python, regex, django

GetUsage/08-03-2011

to match this url i have used following regular expression in urls.py ( python & django)

```
('^GetData/((0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)?[0-9]{2})*',GetData)
```

and inside the views.py following method is configured to accept the date

```
def GetDataData(request,sdate):
```

but when i fire following request

http://[ipaddress]/GetUsage/08-03-2011

i am getting following error

```
GetData() takes exactly 2 arguments (5 given)
```

as it is counting 08-03-2011 in a seperate 5 parts , but i want to get it in a single parameter i.e. in sdate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each regexp group within `()` is being passed to `GetData()` as an argument.  If you don't want groups to be generated by some of them, but still want to use parens, use `(?:whatever)` for non-grouping parens.

EDIT: You probably want something like:

```
('^GetData/((?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](?:0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](?:19|20)?[0-9]{2})*',GetData)
```

Comment: could you please tell me what to alter in url ?